# How do I use Split View in OS X 10.11 El Capitan?

Tags: macos

I downloaded the Developer Preview of OS X El Capitan and I'm trying to use the new side-by-side split view feature.  However, I can't seem to figure out the right incantation to use it.

How do I put two apps side-by-side in a full screen split view on El Capitan?

Comment: Please include the exact build version so we can best help you

Answer (score 8):

It appears that I was doing it wrong.  I don't see a way to enable split-screen from just two fullscreen windows in mission control.  Nor do I see a way to enable it from two regular windows.  But if you have one fullscreen window and one regular window, you can drag the regular window onto the fullscreen in mission control, and it will create a split-screen view.

I tried this successfully with Safari, Finder, and Chrome.

Comment: That was the way shown in the WWDC public demo

Comment: What I can't seem to reproduce is this from the WWDC keynote, which doesn't appear to rely on a single fullscreen window in mission control: http://ak-hdl.buzzfed.com/static/2015-06/8/13/imagebuzz/webdr11/anigif_optimized-32256-1433784346-3.gif

Comment: It also appears that both apps must support full screen as a space. I initially tried to test this with TweetBot, which has the old style maximize button and not the full screen button, and it wouldn't cause a split view to be created.

Answer (score 6):

For the split-screen feature to be available "Displays have seperate Spaces" needs to be *enabled* in the System Preferences of Mission Control:

[image]

Please also note a log out is required if this setting is toggled.

Comment: this was the solution for me, thanks. it was'n stated anywhere...

Answer (score 6):

It's no longer Developer Preview. the solution I just found is:

Press and hold the green fullscreen button, drag the current window to the left/right side of screen, and select the second window for the other half of the screen.

Comment: Yes, I successfully did it following this way. All APPs in my Mac work.

Answer (score 0):

I searched to make It, yet I tested it and worked (magic?) You must click on the Green button on the window, and make a reboot after installed El Capitan :)